# SQL Invalid object name when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am asked to find the teacher's name and titles of all the courses they have taught at least twice.

My database:

```
create table teaches
(ID         varchar(5), 
 course_id      varchar(8),
 sec_id         varchar(8), 
 semester       varchar(6),
 year           numeric(4,0),
 primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
 foreign key (course_id,sec_id, semester, year) references section
    on delete cascade,
 foreign key (ID) references instructor
    on delete cascade
);
create table course
(course_id      varchar(8), 
 title          varchar(50), 
 dept_name      varchar(20),
 credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
 primary key (course_id),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department
    on delete set null
);

create table instructor
(ID         varchar(5), 
 name           varchar(20) not null, 
 dept_name      varchar(20), 
 salary         numeric(8,2) check (salary > 29000),
 primary key (ID),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department
    on delete set null
);`
```

And my code is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT instructor.name, course.title 
FROM    teaches join instructor
            ON teaches.ID = instructor.ID
        join course 
            ON teaches.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE       count(teaches.course_id) > 1
GROUP BY    instructor.name;
```

And it returns the error which said "Invalid object name 'teaches'.
Can you let me know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.  Not `WHERE`.

Comment: Well, if we run your SQL as is then you *do* get that error as we don't have the object `section` in the defintion: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b605c46875f827dd28d029542f8fdd9). If we amend the script to `CREATE` the table `teaches`  *after* `instructor` (as it uses it as a foreign key), and remove references to objects we don't have we get the error @GordonLinoff talks about above, not an invalid object error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e005542ae053171f526bbad0185f2f7)

Comment: Honestly - use the terminology that is appropriate for your schema. You want **instructor** name, not teacher name. Next, stop throwing DISTINCT into a query just to "fix" something. Since you seem to be learning aggregates, your course materials (and documentation) cover the HAVING clause as already suggested. Lastly, your first step should be to simply count the number of courses taught by each instructor. Get that working FIRST and then add the logic for the additional filtering. Lastly - almost every query should include an ORDER clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT i.name, c.title ,count(*)
FROM    teaches t
    join 
    course c
        ON t.course_id = c.course_id
    join instructor i 
        ON t.ID=i.ID
GROUP BY    i.name,c.title
having count(*)>1
;
```

Comment: **DISTINCT** serves no purpose here. Don't encourage or practice sloppy coding.

Comment: that was a type as I copied his code and made the changes. Thanks for pointing out